# Why does the Chewie video player for flutter take up the whole screen size regardless of video dimensions?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, video-player

I am new to flutter, and am trying to play videos in my app. I followed [this](https://resocoder.com/2019/04/13/flutter-video-player-chewie-tutorial/) tutorial on using Chewie to play videos by copying and pasting the code from its `main.dart` and `chewie_list_item.dart` code snippets on the website into a fresh project (the github project provided by the website is too outdated for me to debug, so I did copy pasted instead)

I expected to get something like this, with the player "wrapped" around the video:

[image]

However, I get this (on my android virtual device), with the video player taking up the entire size of the screen regardless of the video dimensions. I did try inputting `AspectRatio` according to the video dimensions, but all that did was to eliminate the stretching of the video, but the main issue remains.

[image]

Why does it behave this way, and how do I achieve the result shown in the first image? This is the test project I made: https://github.com/nathantew14/chewie_test Thanks!

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Comment: @RajaKishan oops it’s been a while but try wrapping the player in an AspectRatio widget